# High impact journals GIS and Remote Sensing

Tags: journals, impact-factor

I am searching for Journals in the area of GIS and Remote Sensing in agriculture and water management, with a high impact factor. It is important that these journals pay authors for their articles ... thanks in advance if you can share even one journal's link.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [What books, journals, electronic resources are most valuable for expanding Geographic Information knowledge?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202/what-books-journals-electronic-resources-are-most-valuable-for-expanding-geogr)

Comment: "journals pay autors for the article" - there are no academic journals that pay the author - there are some that ask the author to pay for a publishing fee (mostly newer open access journals).

Comment: scientific journals or other journals no academic .... May I find in this list such , which pay authors .... etc...

Comment: You can practically guarantee that "pay the author" and "high impact" are mutually exclusive: I put to you the answer is the empty set.

Comment: I listen that there is some journals scientific that pay some honorars to author

Comment: It's actually the opposite: the best journals are in enough demand that many of them actually require the authors (or their institutions) to pay them!  (Payments are nominally for preprints, etc., but they are still just that: payments.)

Comment: This question seems better suited for Academia Stack Exchange. I am requesting a question migration.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is is a better fit for Academia Stack Exchange

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comments above—the idea of journals *paying* authors for articles guarantees that you will not have a high-impact journal. A trade publication might pay an author, but a reputable journal should not.

On the other hand, there are very likely good journals which do not require authors to pay "page charges" to get the article published. But you'll look in vain if you want high-quality and profit!